# Why does Signalr function still exist in the DOM scope when going from one page to another - Single Page App

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

I have created a *Single Page App*, and this is my first one so maybe I'm on the wrong path.

I am using *master-page* in which I'm loading two other pages. Also, I'm using  javascript modules so that I can use private variables and functions.

In the *master-page*, or *Mail.html*, I start the signalr connection, and I initialize the modules.
In the *inbox* sub-page I'm waiting "mail" from the server, and in the *outbox* I'm displaying all sent messages. In order to accomplish this I'm using two different modules (Inbox and Outbox).

My issue occurs when I load the second page (in this example *Outbox*) after *inbox.html* is loaded, in this scenario 
signalr still works which is strange because that connection is used just in the Inbox page, in that module.

I've tried many things to prevent this, like unloading the current page before loading the next one, and I've also tried removing the scripts, starting a connection just in the inbox page, but nothing helps.
Also, I can't find where exactly is this function stored in the DOM when *Outbox.html* is loaded.

Here is my code:

`Mail.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    //scripts
    //css
</head>
<body>

<div class="page" id="Inbox">Inbox</div>
<div class="page" id="Outbox">Outbox</div>

<div id="loadPage">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var SignalRHub = $.connection.hubs;
    $.connection.hub.start();

    var MailModule = {};

    $('body').off('click', '.page').on('click', '.page', function () {

       MailModule = {};

        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'Inbox') {
            $("#loadPage").empty().load("/Home/Inbox", function () {
                MailModule.Inbox.Init();
            });
        }
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'Outbox') {
            $("#loadPage").empty().load("/Home/Outbox", function () {
                MailModule.Outbox.Init();
            });
        }
    });

</script>
<body>
</html>
```

---

`Inbox.html`

```
<div id="items"></div>

<script>
  (function (mail, $) {

        mail.Inbox = (function () {
             var ReceiveMail = function () {
             // This is still active when there is new 'mail' from server
             // even though I'm not on this page
                    SignalRHub.client.receiveMail = function (UserName, Title){
                        $("#items").append("<p>"+UserName+"-"+Title+"</p>");
                    }
                };
             var init = function () {
                ReceiveMail();
            };

            return {
                Init: init
            };
        }());
    }(window.MailModule = window.MailModule || {}, jQuery));
</script>
```

---

`Outbox.html`

```
<div id="items"></div>

<script>
  (function (mail, $) {

        mail.Outbox = (function () {

               var GetSend = function () {
                    $.get("URL", { UserId: UserId }, function (result) {
                        $("#items").append("<p>"+result[0].UserName+"-"+result[0].Title+"</p>");
                    }
                };
              var init = function () {
                GetSend();
            };

            return {
                Init: init
            };
        }());
    }(window.MailModule = window.MailModule || {}, jQuery));
</script>
```

*Note: Maybe this pattern is not right, and I'll be grateful if you give me a lead on how I can accomplish a better one*

Comment: Well single page apps do not refresh the page so the JavaScript that ran before is still there. That is how SPAs work.

Comment: What do you mean the SignalR still works? Is it still connected? How about disconnecting it?  $.connection.hub.stop(); after loading the second page?

Comment: Yes, maybe that will solve the problem, but I can't do that because I still need that connection in order to 'forward' messages in real time..